# How to test function without duplication?

Tags: go, testing

I have a function (main) which calls other functions(sub).
I've written unit tests for sub functions and now want to write a unit test for main function. The question is how do I test main function without duplicating logic for sub functions and assuming their logic in main function test(e.g. mocking calls to DB in them).

Here is an example:

```
type A struct {
    db DB
}

func (a *A) m(i int) bool {
    if a.s1(i) {
        return false
    }

    if a.s2(i) {
        return false
    }

    if i % 2 == 0 {
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func (a *A) s1(i int) bool {
    // some condition check with DB call here
    return true
}

func (a *A) s2(i int) bool {
    // some condition check with DB call here
    return true
}
```

And example testing code(don't check correctness, it's example):

```
func TestS1(t *testing.T) {
    m := &mockDB{}
    m.On("Check", 5).Return(true)
    a := &A{db: m}
    res := a.s1(5)
    if res == true {
        t.Error("got true")
    }
}

func TestS2(t *testing.T) {
    m := &mockDB{}
    m.On("Exists", 5).Return(true)
    a := &A{db: m}
    res := a.s1(5)
    if res == true {
        t.Error("got true")
    }
}

func TestM(t *testing.T) {
    m := &mockDB{}
    // how do i remove this duplication?
    m.On("Check", 5).Return(true)
    m.On("Exists", 5).Return(true)
    a := &A{db: m}
    res := a.m(5)
    if res == true {
        t.Error("got true")
    }
}
```

Comment: You clearly didn't understand the problem. I'm aware of table tests and they are no help here.

Comment: Asserts can be made using https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert which is extensively used.

Comment: I know and use it in real code. It's just an example and I wanted to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `setup`-like semantics if you use `t.Run` to run subtests.

```
func TestSAndM(t *testing.T) {
    // setup mock
    m := &mock{}
    m.On("Check", 5).Return(true)
    m.On("Exists", 5).Return(true)

    t.Run("S1", …)

    t.Run("S2", …)

    t.Run("M", …)
}
```

See a working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/KEmCYcxI0uS

Running subtests: https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Run

Comment: Thank you. Pretty good solution, not perfect though because I did not want main and sub func  testing to overlap. Actually I was also considering changing the structure of code to make better testing.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to go about this is to test only the full flow of your public interface. If your (exported) main function calls your sub functions, then the testing of the sub functions happens in the test of your main function. You won't need to test the sub functions separately, because those functions can be reached only through the main function anyway. If the test of the main function passes, it implicitly means that the sub functions are also passing.

Let's however assume that this is not information you are looking for or information that you already know: if you do want to test them separately - and I guess things could be said in favor of this as well - or if you have multiple main functions calling the same sub function, then indeed you could run subtests like Jonas says, or write a function that wraps the testing of the subfunction and run that function every time a main function calls the sub function. For as far as I know there is no "golden" rule for this.